# Slow Time to The First Byte - XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, apache, performance, xampp

I have a Time to The First Byte (TTFB) of around 1.2s on XAMPP (Apache + PHP 7.2.3) on Windows 10. I tried several PHP configurations, but in the end, I did a test with a static HTML file and got the same results. Therefore, the issue seems not to be on related to PHP, but to Apache (or even to the Operating System).

Do you have any suggestion to obtain a lower TTFB in this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you have some related content in the \xampp\php\php.ini?

Comment: If you mean some configurations in the php.ini file, yes I tried lots of changes, but since the TTFB is long even when I load a static HTML file, I think that it's not related to PHP.